# How can I speedtest my website?

Tags: performance, download

Are there any services (preferably free) which allow you to enter a URL then proceed to download the file from multiple locations and give you the speeds?

Searching has turned up untold numbers of speedtesters for my connection but NOT for a remote website.

To clarify I am looking for a site which will download a file from another site and report the speed at which it was able to download the file. I am NOT looking for a tool to analyse my HTML / page nor am I looking for a tool to report my connection speed.

I realise very simple shell / php / python script etc could be used but obviously I would then need access to various servers elsewhere to use for benchmarking. The desired answer will be a service which provides said infrastructure.

Comment: @yaelalfasi that site is not what i'm looking for. i think it's for analysing HTML. not for download/bandwidth speed testing. 
google really isn't helping- please post any links you think may help

Comment: @yaelalfasi that is test the speed of my internet connection

Comment: i deleted all the junk so other ppl who actually have a clue may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the responses and research I have actually found the best solution to be asking simply asking (on forums for example). One of the best forums seems to be: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?s=5338c05a803046bdc4ee4667f37ff834&f=64

jbowes: Thank your for suggesting gomez http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/ it looks like it is probably capable of doing what i want but i've had no response from them and the lack of pricing on the website suggests it's probably a no-go.

I also had an idea of writing a php script which can somehow connect to a bunch of server and display some output but i'm not quite sure how it would work (wget / curl work in the wrong direction- i want to see the server's upload bandwidth rather than download) and i don't really have to time to spend on it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but [gomez](http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/) will let you write and run scripts on a bunch of geographically distributed servers at specified time intervals, and report results.

You can just write a simple script to download a sample file (or authenticate and download, if necessary), and report on how long the download took.

Gomez [last mile synthetic monitoring](http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/last-mile.html) is probably what you would want.

Comment: is omniture just the software? they don't provide the infrastructure to run those scripts? i could just use shell scripts... i will further clarify my question to say the infrastructure should be provided by the service

Comment: can you point me to somewhere which explains this? i've navigated around the site and haven't found anything informative

Comment: Any documentation I ever used were emailed PDFs from a TAM.

Comment: thanks- i have requested a free trial to see if it can handle the task. can you see any pricing on the website?

Comment: I cannot, and hen I used it, someone else handled purchasing. That probably speaks to how much it might cost, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

[webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/)

Just put in the URL of the file you want to download and select the location from which the download should occur.  This service is intended for HTML, but it will work on other file types as well: just look for the Load Time.  There may be a limit to how large a file it will allow.  I just tried with 1 megabyte of random data.

Keep in mind that the result will be a *lower* bound on the speed of the server you are testing.  In other words, the site you are downloading from might be capable of faster speeds than these results indicate because these results are influenced by whatever is happening on the system doing the downloading.

Comment: really good resource thanks. annoyingly it seems to only download a small amount of the file and doesn't actually output speed (although it can basically be calculated)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple website that will give you the speed to download from a given url from different locations.

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

You can choose from

- Amsterdam
- Dallas
- New York City

I hope this is what you need?

Comment: same as the others i'm afraid- it's meant for testing html page load performance, doesn't really work for file downloads

Comment: I have to admit, i was a bit fast with this answer, it's not measuring the time it takes to complete the download only the loading time of that download.

Answer (score -1):

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Edit: or remote desktop in to your server and run one of those bandwidth testing tools, if you want to measure the server bandwidth in different places.  Most bandwidth tools can test different locations.

Comment: i've had a lot of similar responses which have been deleted because they are speedtests for HTML / web pages not for files/downloads. i'll add some emphasis to the question

Comment: Your question says you want to speed-test a website, and those tools are more important for that, since they measure things like the latency, parsing speed, HTTP header overhead, caching and so on.  If you just want to test your server's bandwidth, run one of your bandwidth tools from the server.  Edited my answer to include this.