# Website is Slow in Certain Locations

Tags: performance, pagespeed

A website I just finished building runs fast for me everywhere I have tested it, but super slow on my clients end. She is located in another city. How can I go about troubleshooting this? I upped the RAM on their server to 256 MB/month.

What causes this? Is this an internal thing with how she is setup on her end? Bandwidth, firewall issue?

I've tried all I can from a coding perspective. Minified styles, configuring cacheing.

http://pickeringmarkets.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions: yes.

Also, a quick note: your page loads fine for me (in DC).

Too many factors can affect the "speed" of a website to warrant a simple "do this" answer. Also, I'm assuming you mean "speed" as server transaction speed (eg: speed of loading the webpage).

---

**Factors**

A brief (incomplete) list of factors that can affect the turnaround speed when a user requests a webpage:

- Quality/performance of the **server** (eg: RAM allowance, processor speed, connection type). (Solution: Get a better server or reduce the "strain" on the sever.)
- [Geographic **location** of the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409374/how-can-i-speedtest-my-website).
- Speed of the **client**'s computer. (Solution: Make your webapp less resource-heavy.)
- **Firewalls** that may need to be traversed between the server and client (and on the server/client's machines as well). (Solution: really, there isn't a way around this.)
- **Size of the files** you're trying to send. (Solution: minify and compress files.)
- The actual **serving program** on the server (eg: Apache, Nginx, node.js, etc.).
- The **network load** or "traffic" server-side and client-side (probably more prevalent client-side). (Solution: tell client's children to stop streaming Netflix.)
- The **browser** that the client is using to view your page. (Solution: tell client to use Chrome.)
- The amount to be rendered/templated on the client's machine. (Solution: do as much templating server-side as possible.)
- The **complexity** of the JavaScript you may be using (if you are using JS that is).

Here's a [nice article from APM](http://apmdigest.com/15-top-factors-that-impact-application-performance) that goes into more detail...

---

**Testing JavaScript and Page-load Speed**

If you are convinced some aspect of your code is actually at fault, [Chrome's Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) have a *Profiles* feature that lets you clock your page's JavaScript as it loads. Then you can actually view where the browser spends the most time. You can also use the *Network* feature to gauge the amount of time spent requesting given files.

Comment: Yes I was referring to server transaction speed. And her setup is in a large building where I'm sure there is a complex setup of networks. I wasn't sure if I needed to contact her IT team who setup her internet.

Comment: One *free* thing you could is have her run a network speed-test from her office; it's possible that her internet at work is the limiting factor. Ookla is generally pretty good: http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: @NatashaMcd FWIW and although your question is off-topic for this forum, the site works fine for me in Europe.